# Check if a substring exists at the beginning, middle and end of a string while allowing intersections

Tags: string, algorithm, search

It sound easy, you can simply iterate and check them, but the problem here is optimization: Don't make any needless checking, needless new objects or operation.

The algorithm will be tested against a huge set of test cases to verify its efficiency.

Examples:

`"aaaa"` contains `"aa"` at the beginning, middle and end.

`"baabaabaaaabbaab"` contains `"baab"` at the beginning, middle and end. See the intersection.

And one more thing I forgot to say:

You are not given the substring to check for, you need to find if such a substring exists, if it doesn't `return false`, if it does `return true`.
Find the longest substring satisfying those conditions and return it, or print it (your choice).

A simple Boolean function, right?

**Update:**

The substring needs to be at least 2 character shorter that the main string.

Sorry, it was my mistake in the "aaa" example, I fixed it.

Comment: Do you want a language-specific answer?  If so, then maybe update your tags.

Comment: Any language or pseudo code

Comment: Do you know the pattern? Or you should find it?

Comment: And … umm … substring.length < string.length, or substring.length <= string.length? :)

Comment: But you said: "longest substring" The string itself always will the best match, and it will be totally O(0).

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you are absolutely right, it needs to be at least 1 character shorter.

Comment: By *two* characters shorter, right? In 'aaa' the solution would be 'a', in the beginning, middle and end. 'aa' is not a solution, because it's in the beginning and end, but not in the middle. Correct?

Comment: If a function is supposed to return more than two different results, it is no boolean function, simple or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it with [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), a string matching algorithm. Using it to generate an array `fail[]`

```
fail[i] = max {k | S[1:k] == S[i-k+1:i]}
```

Then you can enumerate all possible value of `fail[n](fail[n], fail[ fail[n] ], fail[ fail[fail[n]] ] ...)` to check whether it exists in the middle.

The complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: Which language is this?

Answer (score 2):

Let's jump the shark:

```
function the_best_match_at_the_beginning_the_middle_and_the_end( s ){
  print( s );
  return true;
}
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly.  I wish I could just do this for all the unit tests at my job too ^ ^

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you were right, it needs to be at least 1 character shorter or it will be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

One clean way to approach this is to just check all substrings in the input from the beginning.  Compare each substring to see that it exists at the end, and then check to see if it exists in the middle.  For the middle check, you can compare against the input string with its first and last characters removed.

```
public boolean subStrings(String input) {
    if (input == null || input.equals("")) {
        return false;
    }
    if (input.length() == 1) {
        System.out.println(input + " is a match!");
        return true;
    }

    boolean foundIt = false;
    String longestMatch = "";

    for (int i=1; i < inputNew.length(); ++i) {
        String substring = inputNew.substring(0, i);
        boolean endMatch = inputNew.substring(inputNew.length()-i, inputNew.length()).equals(substring);
        boolean midMatch = inputNew.substring(1, inputNew.length()-1).contains(substring);
        if (endMatch && midMatch) {
            longestMatch = substring;
            foundIt = true;
        }
    }

    if (foundIt) {
        System.out.println(longestMatch + " is a match!");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

subStrings("baabaabaaaabbaab");
```

**Output:**

```
baab is a match!
```

Comment: In your question you told us you want the function return true/false, not a string.  I'll assume you want me to _print_ only the longest substring.

Comment: Yes, but the problem in your code is that it rely on brute force, I want to see it there is better (faster) ways

Comment: Sorry, your approach is O(N^2). You loop roughly N times, but you do a string search on each loop. The running time for string search is O(N).

Comment: Where does your OP say the mid match can start from the first position?  Then what distinguishes a beginning match from a middle match?

Comment: This means that middle match has no meaning at all. If only beginning and end substrings match, its fine. Also, OP gives example as in case of `aaa`, o/p is `aaa` and then says that match must be atleast 1 character shorter. Too dubious. @Mr.M

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, it was mistake on my part, the middle match and first can intersect but not completely overlap, I misunderstood the question myself.

Answer (score 0):

That's one of these "you might get significantly better in terms of theoretical complexity, but in reality, linear operation is always faster" answers:

Assuming `in` is your input string, `pattern` is what you're looking for, and you're able to read or look up C-standard-lib-style methods like `strncmp`. Let `l_in` be the number of characters in the input, `l_pattern` the number of characters in the pattern.

Simply explicitely check the start (`strncmp(in,pattern,l_pattern)`); then use a bog-normal linear search from the second letter on (`strstr(in+1, pattern`):

- If `strstr` didn't find anything, there's no middle match nor a end match.
- If it's at the end (result of `strstr` is `l_in-l_pattern`), you've got no middle match.
- If it's not found at the end, you've got a middle match. Manually check (`strncmp(in+l_in-l_patter, pattern, l_pattern)`) for the end match.

Why this is faster? Because modern computers are pretty optimized for searching through data linearly, see [Bjarne "C++" Stroustrup's *why you should avoid linked lists*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo). Simply put, letting your CPU run on a continous amount of memory prefetched to a CPU cache is much much faster than being "clever" about avoiding a few duplicate checks.

Comment: We don't know neither the pattern nor its length

Comment: @Mr.M: Nowhere in the code is assumed you do before starting -- `l_pattern=strlen(pattern)`, if you want pseudo-C.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't mention the values you are giving to the 'pattern', you are starting by either selecting the whole string -1 or the first letter. There are a number of ways.